# PouchDB não está definido

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

Olá, estou usando o PouchDB em meu site para armazenar informações, ele está sendo iniciado no index.html

```
var db = new PouchDB('teste');
```

Ele está funcionando exatamente como eu esperava que ele funcionasse, tem sido bem útil na verdade, porém estou com um problema. Estou tentando fazer a verificação se um item existe ou não dentro do Pouch ao entrar diretamente numa rota específica. Ex:

```
www.siteteste.com/pagina/123
```

Quando acesso a url por esse caminho recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: db is not defined
```

Como posso fazer pra que esse db já seja reconhecido mesmo quando entrar diretamente numa URL composta?

Comment: Não teria que colocar `var db = new PouchDB('teste');` em todas as páginas?

Comment: Ao colocar na página ele cria um novo novamente, e a minha intenção era usar um db que já foi criado anteriormente na index